# Print resultes to file

Tags: python, file, printing

Can somebody help my with mine code. I want de results of the code printed in a .txt file on my system, but i cat an error and i can't resolve it by my self, please can somebody help me with the code ?

```
# Importeer bibliotheek voor systeemfuncties.
import sys
import datetime
import time

############
## Part 1 ##
############
#temperatuur uitlezen
# Definieer een array (temp).
temp = {}

sensorids = ["28-0416b07c2dff"]
# loop net zo lang alles sensors af dat in het array hieboven staan.
    for sensor in range(len(sensorids)):
  tfile = open("/sys/bus/w1/devices/"+ sensorids[sensor] +"/w1_slave") #RPi 2,3 met nieuwe kernel.
  # Lees alle dat uit het "bestand" in een variabele.
  text = tfile.read()
  # Sluit het "bestand" nadat we het gelezen hebben.
  tfile.close()
  # We gaan nu de tekst splitsen per nieuwe regel (\n)
  # en we selecteren de 2e regel [1] (1e regel = [0])
  secondline = text.split("\n")[1]
  # Splits de regel in "woorden", er wordt gespleten op de spaties.
  # We selecteren hier het 10 "woord" [9] (tellend vanaf 0)
  temperaturedata = secondline.split(" ")[9]
  # De eerste 2 karakters zijn "t=", deze moeten we weghalen.
  # we maken meteen van de string een integer (nummer).
  temperature = float(temperaturedata[2:])
  # De temperatuurwaarde moeten we delen door 1000 voor de juiste waarde.
  temp[sensor] = temperature / 1000
  #laatste mogelijkheid
  temperatuur2 = temp[sensor]
  # print de gegevens naar de console.
  #print "sensor", sensor, "=", temp[sensor], "graden."
  print temperatuur2

############
## Part 2 ##
############
#waardes wegschrijven naar text bestand
#Open file
file = open("/home/pi/python_prog/_Log/_temp.txt", "a")

#schrijf waarde testbestand [Tijd: Temp]
file.write(time.strftime("%A %d-%m-%Y %H:%M:%S: " ))
file.write(temperatuur2)
file.write('\r\n')

#file.write()



#Sluit File
file.close()
```

It goes wrong in the "part 2" selection, When i run the script i get the following error:

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python_prog/temp2.py", line 48, in 
    file.write(temperatuur2)
TypeError: expected a character buffer object"

Please can you help me!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file.write(str(temperatuur2))
```

you should be writing strings to files.

Comment: How easy can it be... Thanks a lot!